# Библиотека BeautifulSoup и его методы

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, почему выходит ошибка в цикле, почему он не видит метод .find(),
хотя цикл он отработал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
from bs4.diagnose import lxml_trace

url1 = 'https://4lapy.ru/catalog/koshki/korm-koshki/sukhoy/'
HEAD = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEAD, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items1 = soup.find_all(class_='b-common-item__info-center-block')
    items2 = soup.findAll(class_='b-common-item__info-center-block')

    print(len(items1))
    print(len(items2))

    for items in items2:
        card_title =  items.find('span', class_='span-strong').text
        print(card_title)

def parse():
    html = get_html(url1)
    get_content(html.text)


parse()
```

Comment: потому что элементов класса ``span-strong`` не найдено.

Comment: Надо проверять нашёл ли что-нибудь `find`, бывает, что он ничего не находит, тогда попытка взять `.text` от `None` приводит к такой вот ошибке.

Comment: Проверка на бота от Cloudflare.